Unable to convert the column data and store it in one new column in dataframe pandas
I have a dataframe like below.
    A   B   C
0   3   329430734   998
1   3   329430742   258
2   3   329430776   126
3   3   329430778   998
4   3   329430784   33
5   3   329430851   21
6   3   329430897   998
7   3   329430917   998
8   3   329430943   998
9   3   329430945   998

and I am trying to transform the data in below way to store it in a new column.
df["x"]= np.where((df['C'] == 998) | (df['C'] == 999), max(0, df['A']-1), df['C'] )


However i am getting below while trying transform the column values.
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

I tried to use apply function also using the way below but getting the same error.
def maximum(x, y):
    if ((y == 998) | (y == 999)):
        return (max(0, x-1))
    else:
        return (y)

Unable to find out the issue behind it. Can anyone help me to resolve this issue?

df['A'] and df['C'] are Pandas Series not elements of an iterable as expected by max

Check my answer for apply with function.

You can use np.maximum:
df["x"] = np.where(df["C"].isin([998, 999]), np.maximum(0, df["A"] - 1), df["C"])

   A          B    C    x
0  3  329430734  998    2
1  3  329430742  258  258
2  3  329430776  126  126
3  3  329430778  998    2
4  3  329430784   33   33
5  3  329430851   21   21
6  3  329430897  998    2
7  3  329430917  998    2
8  3  329430943  998    2
9  3  329430945  998    2


Thanks @e-mota for your immediate response. Any idea how to make it using it function and apply method. Have provided a code glimpse above for your reference.

You could use the function you already have in your question, but apply it on axis=1: df["x"] = df.apply(lambda row: maximum(row["A"], row["C"]), axis=1). This will most likely be less efficient than np.maximum, though.

With apply function:
def func(x):
    if x['C'] in [998, 999]:
        return max(0, x['A'] - 1)
    else:
        return x['C']

    
df.apply(func, axis=1)

Output:
0      2
1    258
2    126
3      2
4     33
5     21
6      2
7      2
8      2
9      2
dtype: int64


Your edit is now more or less the same as my solution…

@mozway Oh I didn't see it again. Let me delete it.

I almost deleted mine thinking I had failed to see your solution, then realized it was an edit ;)

@mozway haha yes! Im keeping this now because OP wants a function.

@mozway I'm a bit new here cuz the site looks quite different from before ;)

It's been a while indeed, no winter bash last year :(   welcome back in any case ;)

@mozway Yes haha! You got a ton of rep now!

Similarly to @e-motta's approach, but using mask, and clip:
df['x'] = df['C'].mask(df['C'].isin([998, 999]), df['A'].sub(1).clip(lower=0))

Output:
   A          B    C    x
0  3  329430734  998    2
1  3  329430742  258  258
2  3  329430776  126  126
3  3  329430778  998    2
4  3  329430784   33   33
5  3  329430851   21   21
6  3  329430897  998    2
7  3  329430917  998    2
8  3  329430943  998    2
9  3  329430945  998    2

